# PHP - Error con funcion "array_merge(,,," en entorno local con WAMP en Windows

Tags: php, array, wamp, wampserver

Tengo en local en mi Pc corriendo un sistemita PHP que esta funcionando Ok en PRODUCCION.  La cosa esta que me marca este error en DESARROLLO:

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\DEV\index.php on line 411

Revisando las líneas afectadas me consigo con que el problema que marca es con unas variables de este tipo:

```
$datos = array_merge(...$data_estudiantes);
```

Cuando comento esta linea, todo fluye normal, por supuesto faltan datos por lo que hace esta funcion.

No entiendo porque en PRODUCCION no marca el error y en mi entorno local si.   Estoy usando WAMP.

Alguien puede ayudarme, tengo dias atascado.

Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Seguramente en producción estas usando `PHP v7.4+` y local una versión anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente en producción tienes configurado el entorno para que no muestre errores y advertencias como es común hacer. No se quieren mostrar los secretos al usuario final.
En tu entorno de desarrollo que es donde se necesitan saber las cosas que pasan, está mostrando advertencias y errores y efectivamente esa línea es un error.
El comando array_merge se encarga de mezclar dos arrays, dos variables, y en esa sintaxis está equivocado. Lo correcto sería

```
$datos = array_merge($una_variable, $data_estudiantes);
```

Dado que mezclar variables no es que sea crucial para que siga funcionando, puede que termine incluso en éxito, pero no significa que esté bien. Tendrías que revisar para qué sirve ese merge, y qué debería mezclar.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu importante información y el compartir conocimiento. Sigo investigando como dices. Si consigo solución se las digo.